# Add totals row from 2 different subform and display in textbox

Tags: ms-access

I have two subforms that are each from different queries and both have a totals row. I am trying to sum the field 'Total' from both subformA and subformB together but how would I go about doing that? Is there a way to reference just the totals row?

Any guideline would be appreciated

Comment: You could reference the 'Total' textbox controls themselves directly and total them

Comment: See http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm for reference.